# Twilio | How can I modify call after X duration of dialed?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, incoming-call

Suppose a customer is calling and at the application side staff members(softphone) are busy with some other stuff. I want to play call later text when nobody will answer after X seconds.

I've used a `timeout` attribute of a `Dial` verb. But that directly ends the call.

Any help will make my day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mayank, I am facing the same issue. It would be great if some solution found. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `Dial` timeout is completed, it will either hit the `Dial` action URL or if there is no action URL, the TwiML after the Dial (which isn't preferred since the TwiML after the Dial will play even if the dialed party answers).

Use the `Dial` [action URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) and the [DialCallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) to determine if the call was not answered during the timeout period, `no-answer`, and act accordingly.